# Why STM32 is more popular at industrial devices?

Tags: arduino, stm32, embedded, esp32, accuracy

Well, I am really new started engineer to embedded system. Generally I am using Arduino NANO and its look very easy to use, low power consumtions and lots of library and etc is benefitial for me. But STM32 is more popular in industries devices Such as **Delta** using STM32 at PLC devices, **TS100** Soldering machine using STM32, Also I have wifi modem, I have opened inside it and it has also using STM32. I assume that cars also using STM32. I have suprised. Wrapped all around me with stm32

[image]

I tried to use STM32 with "**bluepill**" and it looks very hard for me. It needs flashing to use, and need usb drivers. If I try to use STCube programmer it looks very strange not clean as Arduino. On the other hand I have tried 2 days for a blink example but I couldnt. Althought this hard to use specifications Why STM32 is more popular, I dont understand?

Well at first, I thougt **performans** and **speed** but there are also ESP32. **ESP32** is much more powerfull than STM32 (bluepill). But I didnt see any ESP32 in any industrial devices. Sometimes I am seeing Arduino NANO at 3D printer. But no where ESP32.

I have watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boF4cX338k4, it talk about **accurancy**, **druability**. well now if I a made Lora wireless communications with arduino nano, will it start to send wrong message in a time? or if I make a wifi project with ESP32, will it start to disconnect from wifi in a time later.

Well, STM32 is disappoint for me, **it is stopping my imagination** because of hard to use, but why so popular industry actually I don't understand. Are there anybody tell why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133906/discussion-on-question-by-mehmet-why-stm32-is-more-popular-at-industrial-devices).

Comment: Going from hobbyist Arduino to bare metal ARM Cortex is a pretty big step. Before the Arduino pandemic struck some 10 years back, people learnt microcontroller programming by fiddling around with a relatively simple bare metal 8 bitter or such. PIC was a popular beginner choice. It's very similar to an AVR, the difference lies in the Arduino bloat libs, which aren't doing anyone a favour. These libs serve pretty much one single purpose: to get something up and running quick & dirty, without having much of a clue how we got there or why.

Comment: It _is_ possible to play around with a bare metal Cortex M as a beginner in a similar manner - the core isn't the problem. The problem is that these have so many complex hardware peripherals that make them beginner-unfriendly. Complex GPIO, pin routing, clock setup, wait states etc etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is - STM32 is much more powerful than AVR. Industrial PLCs and other complex devices need the extra processing power and larger memory capacity, and having that extra power makes complex software easier to write and maintain - which makes it more reliable. Engineers who have developed the knowledge and tools for a particular CPU family will tend to use it for less demanding applications as well.

But for a hobbyist who doesn't need the power it's overkill, and the added complexity makes it more difficult to learn. That is why the Arduino platform was developed, to make it easier for people who are *not* professional engineers to use an MCU in their projects.

> if I a made Lora wireless communications with arduino nano, will it
> start to send wrong message in a time? or if I make a wifi project
> with ESP32, will it start to disconnect from wifi in a time later.

Arduino and ESP32 are not inherently less reliable than STM32. Their hardware is probably *more* reliable than a 'Blue Pill' (most of which have 'fake' CPUs). Software reliability depends on the quality of the code. Code that has proven to be robust is far more likely to work properly than stuff you write yourself (if you manage to get it working at all) and there is a lot of code for Arduino and ESP32 that is being used successfully.

Manufacturers of industrial and commercial products spend millions on R&D and have engineers with decades of experience in their field, so their designs *should* be more reliable (though that isn't always the case). But products like Arduino and ESP32 relieve the user of most of the design effort. Just find an open-source project that is close to what you want, and duplicate it. Then you can try modifying it for your own purposes.

> Well, STM32 is disappoint for me, it is stopping my imagination
> because of hard to use

You wouldn't be the only one. It takes a lot of study to properly understand STM32. Even professional engineers tend to grab a module like Arduino or ESP32 when they just want to get something up and running quickly.